# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page at IF Statement

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I just learn jsp and 
I want to find the minimum and maximum values of each column array
but the statement is in error "if statement"

**Initialization:**

```
double j[][] = new double[14][7];
double min[] = new double[7];
double max[] = new double[7];
double minim;
double maks;
int i, a;
int b;
int k=7;
int jurusan=14;
j[0][0]=50;j[0][1]=60;j[0][2]=70;j[0][3]=80;j[0][4]=75;j[0][5]=60;j[0][6]=70;
j[1][0]=90;j[1][1]=60;j[1][2]=70;j[1][3]=80;j[1][4]=75;j[1][5]=60;j[1][6]=70;
j[2][0]=70;j[2][1]=45; j[2][2]=30;j[2][3]=60;j[2][4]=50;j[2][5]=45;j[2][6]=30;
j[3][0]=75;j[3][1]=25; j[3][2]=50;j[3][3]=50;j[3][4]=80;j[3][5]=25;j[3][6]=50;
j[4][0]=40;j[4][1]=30; j[4][2]=80;j[4][3]=70;j[4][4]=45;j[4][5]=30;j[4][6]=80;
j[5][0]=55;j[5][1]=90; j[5][2]=55;j[5][3]=25;j[5][4]=75;j[5][5]=70;j[5][6]=90;
j[6][0]=30;j[6][1]=70; j[6][2]=30;j[6][3]=45;j[6][4]=65;j[6][5]=55;j[6][6]=50;
j[7][0]=60;j[7][1]=60; j[7][2]=40;j[7][3]=50;j[7][4]=45;j[7][5]=35;j[7][6]=65;
j[8][0]=60;j[8][1]=40; j[8][2]=40;j[8][3]=35;j[8][4]=65;j[8][5]=75;j[8][6]=55;
j[9][0]=45;j[9][1]=70; j[9][2]=40;j[9][3]=80;j[9][4]=90;j[9][5]=75;j[9][6]=65;
j[10][0]=25;j[10][1]=25; j[10][2]=35;j[10][3]=60;j[10][4]=75;j[10][5]=60;j[10][6]=70;
j[11][0]=90;j[11][1]=80; j[11][2]=65;j[11][3]=75;j[11][4]=90;j[11][5]=55;j[11][6]=45;
j[12][0]=35;j[12][1]=60; j[12][2]=55;j[12][3]=35;j[12][4]=45;j[12][5]=90;j[12][6]=80;
j[13][0]=50;j[13][1]=80; j[13][2]=30;j[13][3]=55;j[13][4]=65;j[13][5]=30;j[13][6]=55;
```

**My algorithm to find max and min values each column array:**

```
for (a=0; a<jurusan ; a++)
{
minim=j[0][0];
maks=j[0][0];
for ( b=0; b<k ; b++)
{
 if (j[b][a]>=maks)
 {
 maks=j[b][a];
 max[a]=maks;
 }
 if (j[b][a]<=minim)
 {
 minim=j[b][a];
 min[a]=minim;
 }
}
}
```

> error say "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred
>   processing JSP page /hello.jsp at line 47"

**pointing errors on**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /hello.jsp at line 47

44:     maks=j[0][0];
45:     for ( b=0; b<k ; b++)
46:     {
47:      if (j[b][a]>=maks)
48:      {
49:      maks=j[b][a];
50:      max[a]=maks;
```

> Stacktrace:
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: what is in line 47 ?

Comment: What is the error or exception you are facing? Can you add full stack-trace?

Comment: @LoayAshmawy 
if statement

Comment: Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)